# php foreach loop multidimensional array having issues

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm having problems getting values in my multidimensional arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Brandow & Johnston, Inc.
            [lat] => 34.051405
            [lng] => -118.255576
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Industry Metrolink Train Station
            [lat] => 34.00848564346
            [lng] => -117.84509444967
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => The Back Abbey
            [lat] => 34.095161
            [lng] => -117.720638
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Eureka! Burger Claremont
            [lat] => 34.094572563643
            [lng] => -117.72184828904
        )

)
```

Lets say I have an array such above

And I'm using a foreach loop such as below

```
foreach($_SESSION['array'] as $value){

    foreach($valueas $key_location=> $value_location){

        if($key_location = "name"){$fsq_name = $value_location;}
        $fsq_lat = $value_location["lat"];
        $fsq_lng = $value_location["lng"];



        echo "<i>".$fsq_lat."</i><br/>";

        }

    }
```

I've tried using the if statement, or using `$value_location["lat"];` but its not producing the correct values.

If I do `if($key_location === "lng"){$fsq_lng = $value_location;}` with `three equal` signs, it'll give me errors for a few iterations and then produce the `lng` results. if I just do `one equal` sign and echo it out, it'll give me the `name` key as well.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, `foreach($valueas` appears to be missing a space. Second, are you aware that `if($key_location = name)` sets the variable `$key_location` to `"name"` and then evaluates to true? Use `==` to check equality or `===` to check identity (similar to equality but stronger).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need the inner `foreach` loop. The outer one is sufficient, since it iterates over arrays.  The inner arrays can be accessed by key inside the outer `foreach`.

```
foreach($_SESSION['array'] as $value){
  $fsq_name = $value["name"];
  $fsq_lat = $value["lat"];
  $fsq_lng = $value["lng"];

  echo "<i>".$fsq_lat."</i><br/>";

  // Actually none of the above assignments are necessary
  // you can just:
  echo "<i>".$value["lat"]."</i><br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe refactor a bit?

```
foreach($_SESSION['array'] as $value)
{
    // pull the lat and lng values from the value
    $fsq_lat = $value["lat"];
    $fsq_lng = $value["lng"];
    $fsq_name = $value["name"];

echo "<i>".$fsq_lat."</i><br/>";


}// foreach
```